# Proving the load balancing problem is NP-Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, subset-sum

**The load balancing problem:**
Given we have $m\ge3$ machines (servers) $M_{1}, M_{2},\dots,M_{m}$. As input we are given $n$ jobs defined by their processing times: $t_{1},t_{2},\dots,t_{n}\in\mathbb{Q}_+$ (positive rationals). Our goal is to assign assign the $n$ jobs to the machines so that the maximum runtime of any machine is minimized.

**My endeavour:**
Proving that if $m\ge3$ then this is NP-complete using Subset-sum. This was a proof left as an exercise by our professor. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't delete your question and then re-post it: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150775/755.  As was previously indicated to you in a comment on the previous version: what have you tried?

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style tasks for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Solve it first for $m = 2$, and then show that you can accommodate larger $m$.